# How to check the type of values in a cell array?

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix with two columns, Value and Type.
I want to check the type of data

```
m1 = {'Value','Type'
      'str','char';
      'stra','Real';
      '34','char';
      '2','Bool';
      '1','Bool'
    }
```

How returning values ​​that not correspond to types (reel, char, bool).
Result will be:

```
mError = 'stra'
         '2'
```

Comment: Would '34' comply as 'char' type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If any string is acceptable as 'char':

```
ind1 = strcmp(m1(:,2),'Real') & isnan(str2double(m1(:,1)));
%// Any string is acceptable as 'char', so no ind2
ind3 = strcmp(m1(:,2),'Bool') & ~ismember((str2double(m1(:,1))),[0 1]);
mError = m1(ind1|ind3,1)
```

If numeric strings are not acceptable as 'char' :

```
ind1 = strcmp(m1(:,2),'Real') & isnan(str2double(m1(:,1)));
ind2 = strcmp(m1(:,2),'char') & ~isnan(str2double(m1(:,1)));
ind3 = strcmp(m1(:,2),'Bool') & ~ismember((str2double(m1(:,1))),[0 1]);
mError = m1(ind1|ind2|ind3,1)
```

Comment: it is possible to check decimal value? I tried this: find(round(m1(:,1) == mat(:,1))) without success

Comment: What do you mean with "check decimal value"?

Comment: as I check 'real','char' and 'bool' I want to check float too.m1 = {'1.4','float';'1.3','Real'}     return '1.3' because is not real but decimal(float)

Comment: Sure it can be done. But how do you distinguish a "float" from a "real"? To me they are the same. Maybe you mean "float"/"real" on one hand, and "int" (integer) on the other hand?